# How can i get MPU6050_DMP6 to work with ESP32?

Tags: esp32, mpu6050

I don't really know how to describe this, this is my first time using MPU6050 and i'm using i2devlib.
But whenever i try to upload the example sketch i get:

```
c:/users/win_gaca/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\win_gaca\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\928922B943AB436A6F61171C21D22BE9\libraries\MPU6050\MPU6050.cpp.o:(.literal._ZN12MPU6050_Base7setRateEh+0x0): undefined reference to `I2Cdev::writeByte(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, void*)'
c:/users/win_gaca/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\win_gaca\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\928922B943AB436A6F61171C21D22BE9\libraries\MPU6050\MPU6050.cpp.o:(.literal._ZN12MPU6050_Base20setExternalFrameSyncEh+0x0): undefined reference to `I2Cdev::writeBits(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, void*)'
```

this error goes on much more, but they are similar I2Cdev errors

I am trying to make a drone using esp32. And reading accelerometer and gyro data from mpu6050. But i couldn't get the I2Cdevlib to work with ESP32.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.